# Python libreries for chatbot and installation procedures

Tags: python, flask, installation, chatbot

I'm doing my first project in python and not familiar with python. I'm using visual studio code version 1.38.1 and python version 3.7.3. And using flask framework. I need to create a chatbot. So which are the libreries I have to use and how to install those libreries

Comment: Since you already have flask, you're good to go: You have a good basis for communication with your bot. Everything else is optional, and depends on the behaviors you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

you need nltk library (natural language toolkit ) , scikit-learn , random and string .
as a beginner i recommend this [guide](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-a-simple-chatbot-in-python-using-nltk-7c8c8215ac6e) that can help you create your first chatbot from scratch 
to install libraries just you can use pip3

```
pip3 install nltk sklearn
```

Comment: That's a nice guide that you link to. And +1 for listing the relevant modules, so that your answer is not link-only; that's the way to do it. (`string` is not worth mentioning, though. Not even needed, in my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what types of libraries you want to use depends on how you want your chatbot to work. Google out that first. Regarding installing you can use `pip` to install any library/framework you want. Example: `pip install library-name`